# How to Zoom/Scale an Android WebView in Java

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Actually I have two webviews and I want to zoom/pan other webview based on first webview. For this the application already uses the following code that works fine upto android 3.0 but on later devices it doesnt work. I checked and Exception is thrown i - e Field Not Found exception for mZoomManager.

I'd like to know any alternative for zooming the webview? Can't use webView.setInitialScale();

```
public void setScale(float scale_factor) throws IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        float temp_scale = scale_factor * 0.01f;
        Class<WebView> webViewClass = (Class<WebView>) this.getClass()
                .getSuperclass();
        Field mZoomManagerField = webViewClass
                .getDeclaredField("mZoomManager");
        mZoomManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        Object mZoomManagerInstance = mZoomManagerField.get(this);

        Class<?> zoomManagerClass;
        try {
            zoomManagerClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.ZoomManager");
            Field mInitialScale = zoomManagerClass
                    .getDeclaredField("mInitialScale");
            mInitialScale.setAccessible(true);
            mInitialScale.set(mZoomManagerInstance, temp_scale);

            Field mActualScale = zoomManagerClass
                    .getDeclaredField("mActualScale");
            mActualScale.setAccessible(true);
            if (temp_scale >=1) {
                mActualScale.set(mZoomManagerInstance, temp_scale);
            } else {
                Field mDefaultScale = zoomManagerClass
                        .getDeclaredField("mDefaultScale");
                mDefaultScale.setAccessible(true);
                Object obj=temp_scale;
                mDefaultScale.set(mZoomManagerInstance, obj);
                mActualScale.set(mZoomManagerInstance, temp_scale);
            }

            Field mInvActualScale = zoomManagerClass
                    .getDeclaredField("mInvActualScale");
            mInvActualScale.setAccessible(true);
            mInvActualScale.set(mZoomManagerInstance, 1 / temp_scale);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching for three days I wasn't able to find any solution as I had to give support from android level 8 to 23.

So i came up with using

```
dependentWebView.setInitialScale(mainWebView.getScale()*100);
```

and loading the dependentWebView Again.

The scaling in this case is not perfect. I tried overriding setInitialScale to give it a float value for more accuracy but couldn't do it as scaling is handled differently in different android versions.

Posting this solution so someone else might get help.